# Processing: Using attribute as input for algorithm

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

In Processing Modeller, is it possible to pass a field value (attribute of a feature) to a file name?

Example:

I have raster, **MyRaster.tif**, and I would like to clip it by different polygons inside my **MyClipExtents.shp**. My vector polygon shapefile has 3 features with 2 fields (**ID** and **ExtentName**).

If I use my model, run it iteratively, and output the clipped rasters as TIFs, they all come out with filenames such as MyClippedRaster_**1**.tif and MyClippedRaster_**2**.tif.

Instead I would like them to come out as MyClippedRaster_**ExtentName**.tif

Comment: There is the variable `layer_name` in the field calculator. Maybe you could split your vector data in separate layers and then name the output for the layers?